# Highcharts yaxis negative values error

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighCharts to ploot some graph. I want my y-aixs to range between -1 to +1. When i set max=1 and min=-1 for y-axis, it does not work. Is there another way of implementing this. Below is the my code example.

```
            $(opts.containerSelector).find('.chart-container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: loadLegendSelection
                },
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillOpacity: 0.7
                },
                spline: {
                  marker: {
                    radius: 3
                  }
                },
                series: {
                    events: {
                        legendItemClick: storeLegendSelection
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
            },
            loading: {
                labelStyle: { "position": "relative", "top": "45%", "font-weight": "300", "color": "#29303a", "font-size": "22px" }
            },
            xAxis: {
                gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
                gridLineColor: '#c2dce6',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                min: minDate,
                max: maxDate,
                type: 'datetime',
                labels: {
                   formatter: function() {
                       return formatTimestampTime(this.value);
                   }
                },
                events : {
                    afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes.bind(this, opts)
                },
                minRange: 3600 // one minute
            },
            yAxis: {
                max: 1,
                min: -1,
                endOnTick: false,
                gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
                gridLineColor: '#c2dce6',
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                labels: {                        
                   formatter: function() {
                       return formatMegawatts(this.value);
                   }
                },
                showFirstLabel: false,
                title: ''
            },
            series: convertedData,
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter:
                    function() {
                        return '<b>' + formatTimestampDateTimeWithSeconds(this.x) + '</b><br>' + formatMegawatts(this.y) + ' ('+ this.series.name + ')';
                    }
            }               
        });
```

Comment: Disable startOnTick/endOnTick. It should be enough - but if it does not work, paste your data here.

Comment: That did not work. I found out commenting y-axis.label.formatter function gives correct reading on y-axis but the graph plotted is not correct. Below is my sample data.{1480447380000, 299350},{1480447440000, 11750},{1480447500000, -17550},{1480447560000, 26020},{1480447620000, -18440},{1480447680000, -6060},{1480447740000, -6900},{1480447800000, 18260},{1480447860000, 16880},{1480447920000, -33400}.

Comment: x-axis is date field and yaxis data gets converted using (value / 1000000)

Comment: Can you show the problem on jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/54cr92wd/

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting min and max as given below.

```
yAxis: [{
            max:1,
            min: -1,
            allowDecimals: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#767676'
                }
            },
            offset: -10,
            title: {
                text: 'Inv ' + val_qty,
                "textAlign": 'top',
                "rotation": 0,
                x: 60,
                y: yaxisVal,
                style: {
                    color: '#767676',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        }, {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            endOnTick: false,
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            title: {
                text: y2axisname,
                "textAlign": 'top',
                "rotation": 0,
                x: -75,
                y: yaxisVal,
                style: {
                    color: '#767676',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            },
            offset: -10,
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',
                style: {
                    color: '#767676'
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
```